# A while after I deploy my code to iOS the phone hangs up

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there some way I can track what's happening with Xamarin?  I do a debug with a target of my phone and then later it hangs up. I can't do anything, can't shut it down with the button on the side and the only way I can get the phone to work again is by pressing the button on the side and the home button.  Running on iPhone 6s Plus.

Here is some code that I suspect might be causing a problem.  Would also like to know if anyone can see anything that might cause the problem with the code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public static DataManager db;
    private static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    private const int defaultTimespan = 1;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DataManager DB
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                db = new DataManager();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }


    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        App.DB.InitData();
        MainPage = new Japanese.MainPage();

        if (!stopWatch.IsRunning) 
            stopWatch.Start();

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
        {
            if (stopWatch.IsRunning && stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes >= defaultTimespan)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Checking database");
                PointChecker.CheckScore();
                stopWatch.Restart();
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnSleep");
        stopWatch.Reset();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnResume");
        // deductPoints();
        stopWatch.Start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS requires that everything is setup, with 17 seconds, on the initial first load. This means that you must set the MainPage in your App constructor, you can't set it in OnStart.

Or, you can place MainPage = new ContentPage(); in your App constructor, then it will be replaced in OnStart. However, you must set the MainPage, when it's constructing the Application.

Android and UWP I think, give you some freedom, and you can set it in OnStart, but definitely not iOS.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that and change it.  The app does work but seems like after a while it causes the phone to hang up.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: And by hang up, you mean freeze, or shutdown?

Comment: The phone pretty much freezes. I can see the home page of the phone with all the icons but that's all.  At one point I saw the numbers on the phone to allow me to type my code to start the phone but nothing happened when I pressed those numbers.  Pressing the volume up / down buttons shows the volume change thingy on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhones are hangs up when I have debugger connected to running app and that connection is interrupted. For example, if you unplug lightning cable while Visual Studio is debugging - the phone will hangs. 
So try to start your application from phone(without debugger attached) and check your datacable.

Comment: Okay thanks, this might be the problem I am getting as I do disconnect while debugger is attached sometimes.